# Regular Expression Capturing word/non-word and non-word/non-word boundaries

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a keyword that ends with a word boundary. However, the keyword is dynamic and might ends with a non-word character. Is it possible to match either a word/non-word boundary  or a non-word/non-word boundary?

So for example the keyword is `Hi`, I want it to match `Hi!!` or `Hi Hi` but not `HiHi`. This could be done with `Hi\b`. But if the keyword is `Hi!`, I want it to match `Hi!Hi` and `Hi!!` as well. Using `Hi\b` results in no match.

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand. If the keyword is `Hi`, use `Hi\b`; if it's `Hi!`, use `Hi!`. What's the problem?

Comment: @ruakh I _think_ the keyword is stored in a variable and if you append \b to the variable, you're also appending \b to a potential `Hi!`. I can't say I understand the reason behind those restrictions, however.

Comment: Which language or tool are you using the regex in?

Answer (score 0):

You can either capture word-nonword characters

```
>>> /[\w]+[\W]/.test('hi!')
true
>>> /[\w]+[\W]/.test('hihi')
false
```

Or use boundary symbol to capture character change into non-word:

```
>>> /[\w]+\b/.test('hi!')
true
>>> /[\w]+\b/.test('hihi')
false
```

Or simply use character groups.

Note that boundary symbol is a zero-length value.
There is a wonderful site that explains it all in details: [Regex tutorials](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)